# Character consumption in lexical analysis

Tags: antlr, lexical-analysis

If I have a subrule like the following:

```
.. (~']' ~']')* ...
```

will it only match an even number of characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming the *dots* are not meant as meta characters)

Not quite, it will match *zero*, or an even number of characters.

**EDIT**

To match a quote block, do something like this:

```
QUOTE
    :    '[[' (options {greedy=false;} : . )*  ']]'
    ;
```

Assuming `[[ some text here ]]` is a quote block.

Comment: Oh. Well i am trying to match the end of a quote block, how would you do it? i'm very new to ANTLR :)

Comment: I'm trying this `(options{greedy=false;}:.)*`, will it work in my intended role?

Comment: Also, somehow you hit on lua's exact syntax for string literals and it just so happens that i used the same rule to parse it, so i have a question: would you mind waiving that pesky CC-Wiki license for this little bit of code?

Comment: You're welcome to use whatever I post on SO in whatever way you see fit.

Comment: Cool, thanks, it's highly appreciated, and i'll add a credit to my grammar file thanking you :D